# CRS Options Missing

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, qgis-3, vector-layer

I'm very new to GIS and am trying to use QGIS 3.4.8 to map some spatial data for a larger project. I've been using OpenStreetMap as my basemap, managed to load in my vector layers and for a few days I was able to visualize my data. I opened up my project file later however and noticed a few things:

1. My basemap wasn't lined up with any of my layers, by a huge margin (other side of the continent - see below)
2. The basemap was shifted downwards, and cut off around the equator so only the northern hemisphere is visible (see below).
3. I had about 20 user-defined CRS's, and none of the pre-loaded CRS's that I thought came with QGIS.

[image: Small specks along the top of Canada is my layer; it should be aligned with Southern Canada]

The first thing I did was delete the extra CRS's that I don't remember creating, and try to put all my layers on the same CRS. The problem is, I don't seem to have any of the standard options for CRS:

[image]

Since I'm not trying to do anything more advanced than mess around with the attribute table, all I would really like to do is to line up my layer with my basemap and keep it that way.

Comment: Looks like the projection information has gone, is the Census tracts 2006 layer a shapefile and does it have a .prj file in the same directory? Can you select other on the fly map projections in QGIS?

Comment: It is a shapefile, and does have a .prj file inside the same zipped folder. And no matter which CRS window I interact with (for either layer, or the project), they all seem to be equally devoid of options.

Comment: QGIS indeed should have many pre-loaded CRS's, and they should be visible in the "Coordinate reference systems of the world" section of the CRS window. I can see from your screenshot that the pre-loaded CRS's are missing. Something may have gone wrong with your QGIS installation. Either the CRS definitions weren't properly installed, or they got deleted afterwards (or perhaps a third option that I haven't thought of).

Comment: In terms of troubleshooting, start by closing QGIS and re-opening it. Then try restarting your computer. Then the next step is either to re-install QGIS, or do some more research and see if anyone has explained how to fix this issue. I found this information in the QGIS manual: "Definitions for each CRS are stored in a SQLite database that is installed with QGIS." So maybe you can get a replacement for that database without reinstalling the whole program.